# Botão não acionando função em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

O botão fechar funciona perfeitamente enquanto o botão enviar não aciona a rotina de forma alguma.

```js
$("#incluirItensNoGrid").on('click', function(){
  alert("Hello World!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
  <button 
    class="btn btn-success" 
    id="incluirItensNoGrid()">Enviar
  </button>
  <button 
    class="btn btn-danger" 
    class="close" 
    data-dismiss="modal" 
    aria-label="Close">Cancelar
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O id do botão, mude para `id="incluirItensNoGrid"` retirando o `()` no final, pois você está setando a propriedade ID e não chamando uma função...

Ficando:

```
<div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
<button 
    class="btn btn-success" 
    id="incluirItensNoGrid">Enviar
</button>
<button 
    class="btn btn-danger" 
    class="close" 
    data-dismiss="modal" 
    aria-label="Close">Cancelar
</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#incluirItensNoGrid").on('click', function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ou então mude o seletor para `$("#incluirItensNoGrid()")`, mas a primeira opção é melhor

Comment: Sim. Já fiz e deu certo! Obrigado, amigo!

Comment: Eu fiz a primeira que seta o nome do id corretamente. Novamente, muito obrigado Mirak!

Comment: Acertei?! Então marca como resolvida... :P

Comment: Sim, marquei como resolvida! Parabéns e obrigado pela ajuda!